# How to diaplay image in listview from sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

**how to image display in list view in sqlite db**

```
 SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_column, c
            ,new String[] {"MemberID","Name","Tel","Photo"}
            ,new int[] {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.imageview});
```

> this code working without image but i call image from photo i got error. How can i display image in list view.

Comment: you need a custom adapter

Comment: r u storing image path in sqlite?, if so create custom row layout with  text view and image view then in custom adapter set image to ur image view

Comment: _MemberID,Name,Tel all view in list view but not show image. i want to change string to byte in the photo . how can i change and set photo _

Comment: look at following example which will give u more idea about listview with image and text http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your own custom cursor adapter.

You this as a hint:

```
public class CustomListViewCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = CustomListViewCursorAdapter.class.getSimpleName();


    String[] from;

    int[] to;

    Context context;

    public CustomListViewCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags){

        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        try {

            for( int i = 0; i < to.length; ++i){

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(from[i]);

                String columnValue = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(to[i]);

                textView.setText(columnValue);

            }


            //get your image view and set its content here.
            view.findViewById(R.id.photo).setImageBitmap(yourImageBitmap);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);

        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to write your own layout and use a custom adapter:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Here is a tutorial that can help you: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html